# "Sometimes a * is just a *" meaning and history

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

What kind of expression is it when someone says "Sometimes a horse is just a horse" or "Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar" (Which apparently Freud never actually said)?

What is the history of this expression, and are there any alternative phrases that convey the same or similar meaning?

Comment: http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/08/12/just-a-cigar/

Comment: @YosefBaskin tautophrase! That's a good answer. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **tautophrases**, it is what it is.

> A tautophrase is a phrase or sentence that repeats an idea in the same words. 
>   [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautophrase)

"What's done is done." (Shakespeare's Macbeth)

The name was coined by William Safire in The New York Times.